# increment major and minor version of pom file using sed/awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, gnu

**Requirement 1:**

```
Version - 1.0.0
New Version - 2.0.0 
next - 3.0.0. .... so on
```

Every time only **Major** version should increase .

**Requirement 2:**

Example 1

```
Version - 1.0.0
New Version - 1.1.0 
next - 1.2.0 ... so on
```

Example 2-

```
Version - 2.0.0
New Version - 2.1.0 
next - 2.2.0 ... so on
```

Every time only **minor** version should increase .

How this can be achieve by sed or awk command.

Comment: What happens if increasing minor version of 1.9.0? What happens if increasing major or minor version of 1.9.9?

Comment: For 1.9.0 ->1.10.0 and for 1.9.9 we are not incrementing the patch anyways so if increment major version it become 10.9.9 and if increase minor version then 1.10.9. and for simple major version 9.0.0->10.0.0

Comment: Something like: `echo 1.2.3 | awk -v i=major 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=".";v["major"]=1;v["minor"]=2;v["patch"]=3}{$v[i]++}1' `

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v i=major '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="."
    v["major"]=1               # pick desired version level to increment
    v["minor"]=2               # ... in command line arguments
    v["patch"]=3               # awk -v i=(major|minor|patch) ...
}
{
    $v[i]++
    # for(j=v[i]+1;j<=NF;j++)  # uncomment to reset the lower components to zero
    #     $j=0                 # metoo 
}1' <<< 1.2.3
```

Output:

```
2.2.3
```

or if uncommented the commented out lines of code:

```
2.0.0
```